# Disabling ajax scroll and ajax loader in my jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have added an ajax loader to my code below. The problem is when the data from database is over, still the scroll function is going to an infinite loop and also the ajax scroll image is displayed. I want to stop the scroll function once the data is finished and also disable the ajax loader image. THis is my code

```
var counter=25;
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()==($(document).height()-$(window).height())){
$('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="loading-icon.gif">');
     //Get older posts
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getdata.php?start_row=' + counter,
        success: function(oldposts){
        if(oldposts)
        {
            //Append #postsDiv
            $('#data').append(oldposts);
            counter += 15;
        }
           else
        {

            $('#lastPostsLoader').hide();
        }
        }
    });
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var counter = 25;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
     $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="loading-icon.gif">'); 
     });
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'getdata.php?start_row=' + counter,
      success: function (oldposts) {
        if ($('#data')) {
          $('#data').append(oldposts);
          counter += 15;
        }
      }
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
       $('div#lastPostsLoader').find('img[src^="loading"]').remove();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: if i add your code, the image itself is not being displayed from first, its not working....

Comment: okay! have you tried `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()` functions?

Comment: any errors in console occuring? what is happening with this code currently? just need to know little more about it.

Comment: you can try creating a `.loader` css class with loading image and add it in `.ajaxStart()` function with `.addClass()` and remove it in `.ajaxComplete()` function with `.removeClass()`, This is the way i do ajax calls and it works for me.

Comment: Hey Jai one more problem i am facing is that i am not able to stop the ajax call even if all the data is fetched from db

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, in the success function, if you get the data, you should hide the loader there itself. I am not getting what is the purpose of hiding the $('#lastPostsLoader') in the else part ???

From what I understand is that you are hiding the loader if you dont get any data.

Comment: Yes you are correct mandeep...I want to hide the loader if no data is fetched from db

Comment: for that there is an `error:function(){}` you can put it after `success funtion(){}`

Answer (score 0):

@pavan

```
if ($('#data')) {
//if you have data process your business logic.
}
else
{
 //Hide the loader.
 //remove the event handler you can use .off for it.
}
```

For removing event handler http://api.jquery.com/off/